# Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'seriesNames' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, highcharts, javascript-objects, cube.js

Received a data from api, while trying to render in charts.(I am using highcharts). Its' showing some error in console. Data is rendered perfectly in chart. But i don't know why error is showing in console. Need to clear this. Please help me

```
transformData(resultSet) {    
    const seriesNames = resultSet.seriesNames();
    const pivot = resultSet.chartPivot();
    const series = [];
    seriesNames.forEach((e) => {
       const data = pivot.map(p => [p.x, p[e.key]]);
       series.push({ name: e.key, data });
    });
    return series;
}
```

Comment: As error suggested the `resultSet` must be undefined. Try to put debugger there and you'll find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you get data from an api, then why is `seriesNames` a function on not a object?

Maybe use try this instead

```
    const seriesNames = resultSet.seriesNames;
    const pivot = resultSet.chartPivot;
```

Answer (score 0):

`resultSet` is `undefined`, so you can't get `seriesNames` of `resultSet`:
Please check where call `transformData`

```
transformData(resultSet) {
    console.log('resultSet:');
    console.log(resultSet); // you will see undefined here
    const seriesNames = resultSet.seriesNames();
    const pivot = resultSet.chartPivot();
    const series = [];
    seriesNames.forEach((e) => {
       const data = pivot.map(p => [p.x, p[e.key]]);
       series.push({ name: e.key, data });
    });
    return series;
}
```